# Codepen/JS newbie question: Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, codepen

I started with a Pen brought directly from the tutorial. Its pen settings include the following external scripts:

```
https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js
https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js
```

The following code, close to the original example, works fine:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

function Welcome1(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}

const element = <Welcome1 name="Amy" />;
root.render(element)
```

But then I tried copying in an example from https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-select/ (full code below) that starts with

```
import * as React from 'react';

const App = () => {
...
```

I get the error,
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
at https://cdpn.io/cpe/boomboom/pen.js?key=pen.js-2f18c8b5-7897-1ffd-50bd-9c9c7168f58f:1

What does not help:

1. defining it in the first line as one source on the web recommended:

   var exports = {};
2. deleting the import statement, believing that the pen settings are taking care of that already.

What part of this code is triggering this error, and where do I go to fix it?

```
import * as React from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const options = [
    { label: 'Fruit', value: 'fruit' },
    { label: 'Vegetable', value: 'vegetable' },
    { label: 'Meat', value: 'meat' },
  ];

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('fruit');

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Select
        label="What do we eat?"
        options={options}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />

      <p>We eat {value}!</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const Select = ({ label, value, options, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <label>
      {label}
      <select value={value} onChange={onChange}>
        {options.map((option) => (
          <option value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </label>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I suggest you read the MDN documentation on the export declaration:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

It seems like you are not using modules and as we don't have any information on the environment you are developing your React app in, it is difficult to help you. 

Here's a good guide on setting up you project environment:
https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_getstarted.asp

Good luck on your journey!

Answer (score 0):

## Updated - now I can see your example

Remove your 'exports' line and replace with this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Okay, so its internal paths in error messages are not useful as such. Try this to actually access the example:
https://codepen.io/Joymaker/pen/vYapXVP?editors=1011

With the original import statement present, I saw this odd little warning message that said "imports are only supported as native ES modules. Would you like to replace invalid imports with Skypack? So I played along and clicked okay and even THIS did not make the "exports is not defined" error message go away.

Comment: BTW, Codepen says it's using Babel, I guess that's the environment?

Comment: @Joymaker ok I can see the problem. See my update

Comment: Thanks, Steve, that was a step in the right direction. The example code given contained

    "React.render(<MySelect />, document.body);"

which I'm guessing is an out of date way of saying things. Your way makes it happier. But here's what really worked: changing line 4 to remove "export default". Weird, huh?

Am I just caught in some spiraling time warp of different versions of React?